# Implementing LDAP with exsisting user base

Tags: 6, users, authentication-authorization

We are in the experimental stages of implementing LDAP in our Drupal 6 environment, using the [LDAP integration](https://drupal.org/project/ldap_integration) module. LDAP is installed and working in our dev environment and now we are looking at different transition plans. We have a fairly substantial user base (couple hundred user in the DB) although realistically we have only a few dozen active users.

My first thought is to go 'cold turkey' and just drop the Users table and ask all users to just start using LDAP for authentication. I tried this in dev, and while authentication worked, some pages would not load, and I'm wondering is this because there is no longer a user associated with these pages?

So along with the specific question above I'm wondering what is the best path for a transition to LDAP on a server with an existing user base? We cannot reliably key off of a username or email to 'sync' the users. That is why I am inclined to start with a clean user table if I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our goal was to 'clean up' the hundreds of old users in the system so rather than try and do some sort of merge, here is what we decided on.

First we will export the node and user tables so we can restore these if anything goes wrong.

Next we will update the node table and set uid to '0' for all nodes. uid is the author that is associated with a node. Setting the uid to 0 associates the node to the anonymous user. If you don't do this, when you drop the user table then you have an orphaned node associated to a uid that does not exist.

Next we will truncate (drop all rows) in the user table except for users 0 & 1 (anonymous and admin users).

Thats it. The disadvantage is that our users will lose there 'My Content' pages. We hope to mitigate this by sending emails in advance and telling our users to make note of pages they own. Additionally we may try and do a query that will list all pages and their users.

Answer (score 0):

You could try having them create the new LDAP accounts and then merging the users. [User Merge](https://drupal.org/project/usermerge)

> This module helps users to merge together duplicate accounts. It uses a hook system so other modules can do whatever they need to manage their relationships to users.